# How developer key is necessary in youtube api android?

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

I am able to get all the data through `search result` using the [**link**](http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?v=2&alt=jsonc&q=Katrina%20Kaif%20hot%20vidoes&max-results=5) and can play the video in the installed `youtube` app of the device from the link with the help of `youtubeapi jar`.

```
Intent videoIntent = YouTubeIntents.createPlayVideoIntent(this,
            "y4cJxadBTVU");
    startActivity(videoIntent);
```

Where does the `Developer key` comes into play??

Is it for version 3?

First time i am dealing with `youtube api`

Any help/suggestions would be highly appreciated..

Thanks

Comment: It is often being used when you need to do some API Query, for example querying video result base on query term. Also, since you're using YouTubeIntents, I believe you're implementing YoutubeAndroidPlayerApi library, in this library they offer you ThumbnailView and YoutubePlayerView,  these are the classes where you need a developer key to call. As for what you're doing, it doesn't require any.

Comment: If i want to implement youtube player into the app, then only we need  Developer key?

Comment: YoutubePlayerView is a class, its a view object like ImageView where you can declare in xml layout file, to initialize the view with a video, you need a developer key. But if you're just doing what inside your question, you don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments and my own experience I can answer this question.
Developer KEY is not required in case using only `YoutubeIntents` since it opens videos in Youtube app which already has necessary privileges to open any public videos.
In my app I am using exactly the same class and I don't have any extra API enabled on Google Developer Console, neither need any key.

Although, I am not sure if it works if you try to open some private videos, I would expect YT app to prompt user for valid authentication, I guess.